# Mechanism of decomposition of N2O5

Tags: kinetics

In my book mechanism of decomposition of $\ce{N2O5}$ was given like

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Reaction:}\\
\\
\ce{2 N2O5 &-> 4 NO2 + O2}\\
\\
\mathrm{Mechanism:}\\
\\
\ce{N2O5 &<=>[k_1][k_2]NO2 + NO3}\\
\ce{NO3 + NO2 &->[k_4]NO + NO2 + O2}\\
\ce{NO3 + NO &->[k_3]2 NO2}
\end{align}

But on stack exchange somebody gave mechanism of decomposition  like this at [Steady State Approximation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/59632/120436).

Pls tell which one is correct and why it is correct?

Comment: Which one do you think is correct?

Comment: Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts. 

Suitable formatting can be done according to [formatting math/chem expressions/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: Now I  see I have copied the img error too, as there are 2 different $k_2$. Turning one of $k_2$ to $k_4$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of all the elementary steps in the mechanism must result in the overall balanced equation:

$$\ce{2N2O5(g)->4NO2(g) +O2(g)}\tag{R}$$

If we add up each one in your book's proposed mechanism:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\ce{\ce{N_2O5(g)} &<=> \cancel{\ce{NO2(g)}} +\cancel{\ce{NO3(g)}}} \tag{R1} \\
\ce{\cancel{\ce{NO3(g)}} +\cancel{\ce{NO2(g)}} &-> \cancel{\ce{NO(g)}} + NO2(g) +O2(g)} \tag{R2} \\
\ce{NO3(g) + \cancel{\ce{NO(g)}} &->2NO2(g)} \tag{R3} \\ 
\hline
\ce{N2O5(g) +NO3(g) &-> 3NO2(g) + O2(g)} \tag{R'}
\end{align}
$$

We can see that R' is not the same as R, so this mechanism is incorrect.

Conversely, doing the same with the other proposed mechanism:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\ce{\ce{N_2O5(g)} &<=> \cancel{\ce{NO2(g)}} +\cancel{\ce{NO3(g)}}} \tag{R1} \\
\ce{\cancel{\ce{NO3(g)}} +\cancel{\ce{NO2(g)}} &-> \cancel{\ce{NO(g)}} + NO2(g) +O2(g)} \tag{R2} \\
\ce{N2O5(g) +\cancel{\ce{NO(g)}} &->3NO2(g)} \tag{R3} \\ 
\hline
\ce{2N2O5(g)&-> 4NO2(g) + O2(g)} \tag{R''}
\end{align}
$$

Where we can see that R'' is the same as R.

We cannot conclude solely based on this that the second mechanism is necessarily correct, but we can conclude that the first mechanism is necessarily incorrect.

Comment: But on internet it is given the given same mechanism as my book mentioned https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Kinetics/04%3A_Reaction_Mechanisms/4.12%3A_Steady-State_Approximation see this.

Comment: @ArijitSingh $\ce{NO3}$ is an intermediate in this case, so it does not make sense for it to stay (not be readily consumed) and appear as a reactant for an overall reaction that does not include it in the first place.

Comment: This reaction has been studied and [the mechanism](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja01541a019) has been given as exactly as one given in OP's text book.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne I do not have full access to the paper you cited, but from the first page at the bottom, reaction (g) is not included in OP's mechanism.

Comment: For the book's mechanism, just multiply the first step (R1) by two to get the correct stoichiometry. The question is whether $\ce{N2O5}$ reacts directly with NO, or only after it dissociates. Otherwise, the two mechanisms are identical.